# Distance Euler's Line

Tags: geometry

In a triangle ABC, H, G, and O are orthocenter, centroid, and circumcenter of the triangle. If the Euler's  line is parallel AC and m <(HBC) = 2m <(OCA), calculate GO if AH = a (answer: a/3)

I tried to draw the triangle and relate the properties but couldn't find a solution.
We know that GH = 2GO and BG = 2GP
Triangle BHG ~ POG
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the equality of (measures of) angles:
$$
\widehat{HAC}
=90^\circ -\hat C=\widehat{HBC}=2\cdot\widehat{OCA}
= 2\cdot\widehat{OAC}\ .
$$
This implies:
$$
\widehat{HAO}
= \widehat{OAC}
= \widehat{AOH}\ .
$$
The triangle $\Delta HAO$ is thus isosceles in $H$, so $HA=HO=3\cdot GO$.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I don't understood : HAC = 90 - C = HBC    . Can you explain better? If possible, draw your solution,

Comment: I will use the inserted picture from the OP. Here, the angle $\widehat{HBC}=\widehat{H'BC}$ complements the angle in $C$ in the triangle $\Delta H'BC$, since $BH'$ is the height in $\Delta ABC$. So $\widehat   {H'BC}+\underbrace{\widehat   {H'CB}}_{=\hat C}=90^\circ$. Same applies also for the situation of $HA$ instead of $HB$ (although the full height is not drawn).